# Android - Save Large Xml File (Internal / sdcard)

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sd-card, out-of-memory

I want to save an online xml file which is very big in size(around 33mb). I am trying to get the xml file in a StringBuilder, convert in into string and then save the file in internal storage / Sdcard by FileOutputStream.

But i am getting Out of memory and the app crashes. The crash occurs when i try to get the value in string from StringBuilder.

Here is my current code :

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("sorry cant paste the actual link due copyrights.xml");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();            

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        String result = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(result);

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());

        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your soulution is that it requires a lot of app-memory because the xml-string is loded completely into memory.

You can avoid this by processing the data in litte 1kb chunks like this:

```
    is = httpEntity.getContent();

    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    is.close();
```

Comment: Trying this as well, will let you know the result.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the code below?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    sb.append(line + "\n");

    if (sb.toString().length() > 10000) {
       fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
       fos.flush();
       sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
is.close();

fos.close();
```

Comment: I will surely try this, will let u know ASAP.

Comment: This is working perfectly well, but @k3b method seems to work better than this. Thanx for the answer.